# Plot histogram with index values on x axis and frequencies of each column value on y axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Based on the dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cat1':[100,0,0,5],'cat2':[5,20,50,0]})
df 
    cat1    cat2
0   100 5
1   0   20
2   0   50
3   5   0
```

I want to plot a histogram such that the x axis represent the index values 0 to 3 and the bars for each index value show the distribution of the column values cat1 and cat2.

```
df.plot.hist(alpha=0.5)
```

plots the index values on the y and the category values on the x axis:

[image]

And

```
df.transpose().plot.hist(alpha=0.5)
```

results in something I don't even fully understand:

[image]

What I actually want is a bar for each index value, that illustrates the values in the columns - e.g. for index 0, there should be a bar in cat1 color stretching to 100 on the y axis, containing another bar in cat2 color stretching to 5.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it's close that what you want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.barh()
plt.show()
```

Update thanks to SpghttCd:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df.plot.bar()
plt.show(
```

Comment: ...and isn't `df.plot.bar()` even _exactly_ what they want? why explicitely horizontal?

Comment: Yes you're wright, I didn't know that the 'h' was for horizontal.

Comment: and I don't think that you need `plt.show()`, therefore also no import of `matplotlib.pyplot` necessary - but this might depend on the dev envoronment...

Answer (score 1):

you can use the pandas viz functions :

df.plot.bar(stacked=True)